# Change scss file location with express-generator not working

Tags: node.js, sass, express-generator

So I have followed the instructions to scaffold a new project with express-generator latest version. Upon creation, I have done the npm install and everything went ok. Under the express-generator options, I passed pug as the view engine and sass as the style. Once the project has been created I found that the .css files are next to the .scss files so I made new folder under the public folder called sass to store all my .scss files, then I change the src path in the app.js file to public/sass, and I only have two files under the sass folder the one that the generator created and other with one variable color defined to test the import. But as soon as I moved the files into this new location changes in variable color are not being made, if I move the files back to the original location they work, can someone tell me what is going on?

```
app.use(sassMiddleware({
  src: path.join(__dirname, "public", "sass"),
  dest: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
  indentedSyntax: false, // true = .sass and false = .scss
  sourceMap: true
}));
```

Comment: Check your sass files for includes.

Comment: I only have one folder called sass, inside of it I have one file called styles.scss which only has an @import "partials/basics"; and inside that sass folder i have another folder called partials with the file basics.scss with just $black: #000000;

Comment: Do you have the `partials` subfolder in the `public\sass` folder ? It has to be `@import "basics"` if both files are in same folder.

Comment: yes, I do have the partials subfolder inside the sass folder, and that is why my import starts by the name of the subfolder, but even if I change that and take that partials folder out of the way and change the import nothing is being piped into the style.css file that is supposed to. Not even if i write a simple backgound color change directly in the style.scss file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sassMiddleware is actually looking for a specific folder structure so when I change the public directory for sass, it is expecting inside the sass folder another folder called stylesheets, and inside this new folder I can put any scss files, and now it is working, thanks to all.